# How to upload data to a related list that has not yet been started?

Tags: record-type, related-list, upload

In our volunteer record type, we have a related list that has several key data points that are in a .csv file.

How can I mass upload this data to the related list fields if the "new application" in the volunteer record type has not yet been created?

Is there a way to mass turn on the "new application" related field for all of a specific record type and then do my mass upload?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external ID for the "new Application" records you could use upsert and it would create the New Application records when inserting the children.

otherwise, you will need to have the parent records created prior to inserting the Children.